# keep most recent commit and remove previous 3 comit?

Tags: git

For example I do a `git log`: showing that I have 5 commit:

```
commit 1

commit 2

commit 3

commit 4

commit 5.
```

Now I want to keep commit 1, but remove commit 2, 3, 4. So after do it, my `git log` should looks like:

```
commit 1,

commit 5.
```

What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: `git rebase -i HEAD~7`

Answer (score 2):

One way to proceed is to interactively rebase ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---interactive)).

The other would be to reset to 1 and cherry-pick 5 :

```
git reset --hard <hashOfCommit_1>
git cherry-pick <hashOfCommit_5>
```

(you can find the hashes with `git log --oneline -5` for example)

However, note that it rewrites history of your branch. If the commits after 1 have already been pushed to a remote repo, you'll have to

```
git push --force origin HEAD
```

to update the old reference.